# ElasticSearch Get Value of Nested Attribute

Tags: indexing, filter, elasticsearch, nested

I have this structure in index:

{ details: {errors:[], warnings:[], results:[]}}

I want a query so that I can get the count of errors warnings and results for each record.

I was looking into the script filter on an aggregate, but the thing is I am already aggregating and I'm unsure on how to use the value count filter with this since I need to

1) Get the .length attribute of the array
2) When I do that I get an error saying no attribute like that exists

Can I get a sample query? I'm guessing it will somehow incorporate the script filter.

Comment: Please, provide more convinient mapping. What is errors/warnings/results?
Json array? Object? Nested object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to achieve this is the token count data type told in the below link
LINK - http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/mapping-core-types.html#token_count

You can couple this with multi fields to achieve an extra field per error , warning and results. This can be used in the query to view the count of elements.